# Uploadify jQuery question3 new permission

Tags: jquery, uploadify, jquery-file-upload

In jQuery uploadify while upload a file its show the progress bar to show the process.When its come to 100% or its completed file is remove one by one from queue.

i want to know that while file is completed to 100% it should not be remove un till the cancel button is not press file should be remain there only

**means file attachment in uploadify.**

that is my code of uploadify please give any idea regarding this.

```
  $('#uploadify').uploadify({
                // var val = document.getElementById("giveresponse").value;
                'uploader': 'swf/uploadify.swf',
                'script': '<%= request.getContextPath()%>/vendor.UploadTicket.form?',
                'folder': '/uploads',
                'queueID' : 'fileQueue',
                'cancelImg': 'swf/cancel.png',
                'fileDataName': "fileData",
                'fileExt':<%=allowedFile%>,
                'fileDesc':<%=allowedFile%>,
                'scriptData' :{'ticketId': '<%= supportTicket.getTicketId()%>','action':'savegiveResponse','vendorId':'<%= vendor.getVendorID()%>'},
                'multi' : true,
                'onUploadStart' : function() {
                            alert($('#giveresponse').val());
                            $('#uploadify').uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'giveresponse':$('#giveresponse').val(),'oldId':'<%= lastResponseId%>' });
                        },
                'onSelectOnce' : function() {

                    $('#uploadify').uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'giveresponse':$('#giveresponse').val(),'oldId':'<%= lastResponseId%>' });

                },


                'onAllComplete'  : function() {  alert('Files Upload Successfully');document.getElementById("giveresponse").value = ""; location.reload();}
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
$('#uploadify').uploadify({
// var val = document.getElementById("giveresponse").value;
    'uploader': 'swf/uploadify.swf',
    'script': '<%= request.getContextPath()%>/vendor.UploadTicket.form?',
    'folder': '/uploads',
    'queueID' : 'fileQueue',
    'cancelImg': 'swf/cancel.png',
    'fileDataName': "fileData",
    'fileExt':<%=allowedFile%>,
    'fileDesc':<%=allowedFile%>,
    'removeCompleted' : false,
    'scriptData' :{'ticketId': '<%= supportTicket.getTicketId()%>','action':'savegiveResponse','vendorId':'<%= vendor.getVendorID()%>'},
    'multi' : true,
    'onUploadStart' : function() {
        alert($('#giveresponse').val());
        $('#uploadify').uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'giveresponse':$('#giveresponse').val(),'oldId':'<%= lastResponseId%>' });
    },
    'onSelectOnce' : function() {

        $('#uploadify').uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'giveresponse':$('#giveresponse').val(),'oldId':'<%= lastResponseId%>' });

    },


    'onAllComplete'  : function() {  alert('Files Upload Successfully');document.getElementById("giveresponse").value = ""; location.reload();}
    });
```

Set a new option -> 'removeCompleted' => false

Also view my comment and try your best next time :)

**EDIT:**

So you want to be able to remove a selected file from the queue of uploaded files?

```
$(function() {
$("#file_upload").uploadify({
    'auto'     : false,
    'swf'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'onCancel' : function(file) {
        removeUploadedFileFromTmp( file );
    }
});
```

});

```
// JavaScript(JQuery AJAX)
function removeUploadedFileFromTmp( file ) {
    $.ajax({
      url:'../your_website/removeUploadedFile',
      data: { file_name : file }
    });
}

// PHP (Or whatever else you're using)
public function removeUploadedFile()
{
   $files = scandir( "Yoursourcepath/yourtempfile" );
   foreach ( $files as $file )
   {
       if ( in_array( $file, array( ".", ".." ) ) )
       {
           continue;
       }
       if ( $file == $_POST['file_name'] )
       {
          unlink( "Yoursourcepath/yourtempfile" . $file );
          break;
       }
   }
}
```

Everything is in the uploadify docs -> http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/.

The exact documentation you might need:

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/oncancel/

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: My Question is that i want attached file like Gmail.

Comment: 1) First attached file in compose the in gmail 2) you can see the attached file or remove the attached file in gmail

Comment: did you understand my question Igor Lacik

Comment: example like GMAIL compose

Comment: removeCompleted option is there in Uploadify jquery